# Proteus, Ares, Isis - how to combine LYT and DSN?

Tags: pcb-design, proteus

I have inherited some old files from a Proteus project, .DSN and .LYT files. Is there any way of combining them into a project file so new Gerbers can be generated etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Import the files into Proteus 8 and it will save the project as a .PDSPRJ file which all is included.

Kind regards,
David Spencer - Labcenter Electronics."