# Proteus - Schematic and Gerbers to Layout?

Tags: layout, proteus, gerber

We have a problem with an old PCB designed using Proteus. We only have the schematic and the Gerber output. Is there any way we can regenerate the layout from those?

Answer (score 0):

Older designs had separate schematic and layout files, newer project designs merge them into a single file.

Have you tried using "File" > "Import Legacy Project" to see if that will merge the existing separate files into a single project?

[image: Proteus 8 File Menu]

Comment: Gah, looks like you already knew this, @Dirk Bruere.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136161/proteus-ares-isis-how-to-combine-lyt-and-dsn?rq=1